# Global variable or context between Intent - Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new to Dialogflow and trying to figure out about Context and different Intent.

Basically my need would be to be able to trigger the same Intent with or without a context. But it's seem that it's with or without but not in between.

Here is what I'd like to be able to do:

Imagine a user that ask about Events in a specific Region, then we could give him a response saying : "Don't miss the XYZ Festival in Quebec this Weekend!".

Then, just after, the user asks about the Weather : "How will be the weather this Weekend?"

I'd like to be able to give him the answer for Quebec, because the Event is there and as human we would understand that the second question is about the first.

This is possible with context set as Output Context in EventIntent and Input Context in the WeatherIntent. But inverse could happen.
User can ask about the Weather in a specific region and then ask for Events there. If I set the Input Context in Weather, then it will never be triggered without that context. And if I don't set the Context, then it will ask for the region again.

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track using Contexts, but you're missing how Input Contexts are used.

Setting an Input Context on an Intent means that Intent can be triggered **only** when that Context is valid. If no Input Context is listed, however, then it will be valid at any time - and you can still use the Context as long as it is valid (ie - as long as it hasn't timed out).

So you can set the location parameter by setting an Output Context (either in the Intent description or, better, in your webhook). Then have phrases for your "EventIntent" and "WeatherIntent" that both take the (optional) location parameter and not. In your fulfillment you might use logic such as this:

1. If the location parameter comes from the phrase, then return answers based on it and save it in the Context for future use.
2. Otherwise, try to get the location from the Context and return answers based on that.
3. If you can't get a location at all - ask for it, and then return answers based on that reply.

Comment: I believe this is the right answer as it clarifies the impact setting an input context has on the intent detection. However, when it came to retrieving the context variables I'm still with no answer. Retrieving the "local" context variables set as input context of an intention is easy since it's available in its webhook. But I have yet to find how to retrieve the global context of a Dialogflow session. Thanks